# Does publishing a private app in google managed store should meet minimum API level requirement?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console

I want to publish a private app for the customer, to his managed play store, using his organisation ID. Does my app has to meet minimum API level requirements and other requirements which are set for public store.
Which release track do I need to choose for publishing a private app for customers ?

Should I do it from Admin Console or play console ?

Comment: yes of course. Why would the requirements be different

Comment: I am not publishing to public store . It is the private store for my organisation, then why am I compelled to fullfill these requirements ?

Comment: What If , I am uploading the private app via EMM console ? Why there is no such limitation when uploading via EMM console

Comment: It is meant for same "Managed play store" but the requirements to fullfill are different if you upload via EMM console and play console , Why ???????